# Rcmdr package in R cannot open

Tags: r, r-commander

I cannot open the Rcmdr package, some output like this popped up:

```
Loading required package: splines
Loading required package: RcmdrMisc
Loading required package: car
Loading required package: sandwich
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'RcmdrMisc' in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called 'gridExtra'
Error: package 'RcmdrMisc' could not be loaded
```

What should I do? I have zero knowledge in R. Please help!!!!

Comment: I could not install that package

`Error in install.package("gridExtra") : 
  could not find function "install.package"`

appeared @MarcoSandri

Comment: It should be `install.packages("gridExtra")` (there's an "s" in there, easy to forget)

Comment: @MrFlick Thank you!!!! I got the package downloaded!!!!